# Searching in mongodb atlas on express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

hi everyone i have data on mongodB atlas this is my mongoose Schema
[mongoose Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp3Gq.png)
and this is client
[client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUsUj.png)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";

import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import { getPosts } from './actions/posts';
import useStyles from './styles';
import memories from './images/memories.png';

const App = () => {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [currentId, dispatch]);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg" >
      <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
        <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center">Search Bar</Typography>

        <SearchBar  />

      </AppBar>
      <Grow in>
        <Container>
          <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
              <Posts setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} >
              <Form currentId={currentId} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </Grow>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

use this https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-search-bar

to Search i try to use "Mongoose Fuzzy Searching Plugin"
i do this [Mongoose Fuzzy Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI1kX.png)

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import mongoose_fuzzy_searching from 'mongoose-fuzzy-searching';

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    message: String,
    creator: String,
    tags: [String],
    selectedFile: String,
    link:String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(),
    },
})
postSchema.plugin(mongoose_fuzzy_searching, { fields: ['message', 'title'] });

var PostMessage = mongoose.model('PostMessage', postSchema);

export default PostMessage;
```

what i need to write in router? i don't understand...
and how i displays the results in react?
In addition, how i can URL validation?

Comment: Stack overflow (SO) allows embedding code in the post.  Rather than have a link to an image of code, please paste in the actual code directly into the post so people who want to help do not have to retype in the example code to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the fuzzy search with your backend API just like that

```
await Product.fuzzySearch(search).find()
```

Comment: i do this i put down

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const SearchPost = async (req, res) => {

    const search =  req.body.search;

    try {
        const search = await PostMessage.fuzzySearch(search).find();

        res.status(200).json(search);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```